# How to force gradle to trust maven central repo?

Tags: gradle, tls1.2, java-11, tls1.3

I get this error when trying to build with gradle `./gradlew build`:

```
...
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.15.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.15/httpcore-4.4.15.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.15/httpcore-4.4.15.pom'.
           > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
              > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
              ...
```

Seems unlikely that maven central does not support any of the TLS protocols.

Here's my gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/jdk-11.0.5+10
org.gradle.allow-insecure-protocol=true
systemProp.scan.uploadInBackground=false
```

I have tried with:

Gradle versions 7.0.2 and 7.3.3

JVM versions OpenJDK 11.0.5+10, Oracle JDK 11.0.13 and OpenJDK 11.0.14+9

Same propblem with all of them.

Also I have tried to:

1. Import manually repo.maven.apache.org certificate to lib/security/cacerts.
2. Replaced `mavenCentral()` with

   ```
    maven {
       url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/"
       allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
   ```
3. Removed `SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1` from `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` on newer JDKs in conf/security/java.security

What else to try?

Comment: Is it possible that your company has a man-in-the-middle SSL/TLS proxy?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no, it was configuration issue, I added solution to question, so I cound find it in future.

Comment: Please post the solution as an *answer* instead of adding it to the *question*.

Comment: Move it to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a facepalm. My `build.gradle` had following lines:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "my-keystore.jks")
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "s3cret")
```

which contained expired certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and finally solve the issue according to the [gradle document](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties) by adding the `https.protocols` in `gradle.properties`

```
https.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```